# Is there an SNMP appender for log4net?

Tags: log4net, snmp

Please read carefully, I'm looking for an SNMP (not SMTP) trap appender for log4net.  Log4j has an SNMPTrapAppender and I have not seen an equivalent for log4net.  Does anyone know of an appender that already does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the following [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-254) on Log4Net. It is a patch, but the JIRA contains the SNMPTrapAppender source and a sample on how to define the config.